# How to reorder ITestCaseCollection using C#

Tags: c#, linq, tfs

I am currently writing some program to download Test Cases information from TFS server. Our user require the Test Cases to be downloaded in their desired sequence.

Current program is using this piece of code to download all test case information in a test case collection from a selected test suite. However, the default ordering is by TFS server system Test Scenario/suit ID => then Test Case ID. Our user would like to sort it based on the Test Scenario/suit name => Test Case name instead.

```
private ITestCaseCollection testCases;
```

`private void Get_TestCases(ITestSuiteBase testSuite)`
        {

```
        this.testCases = testSuite.AllTestCases;
        if (NoSubSuite.Checked == true)
        {
            this.testCases.Clear();
            foreach (ITestSuiteEntry tse in testSuite.TestCases)
            {
                if (tse.EntryType == TestSuiteEntryType.TestCase)
                {
                    if (tse.TestCase != null)
                    {
                        testCases.Add(tse.TestCase);

                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

How to achieve the sorting by name? 
I found there's an extension method for ITestCaseCollection which is called orderby. But I have no idea how to use it, I can't find relevant documentation on MSDN as well. Can anyone help?
[image: testCases.OrderBy extension method]

Comment: It is bad practice for test cases to require a sequence! They should be independent...

Comment: My user would like me to show the test cases information in a specific sequence as they required.. It's for displaying the information only :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `List<TestCase>` with the order you want using `OrderBy` something like this:

```
var list = testCases.OrderBy(t => t.ScenarioName)  /* or whatever properties */
                    .ThenBy(t => t.Name)
                    .ToList();
```

I don't know how to build an `ITestCaseCollection` from it, though you may not need to do that.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I sort the list and clear my original ITestCaseCollection then add them back.   `var templist = testCases.OrderBy(t => t.TestSuiteEntry.Title)
                .ThenByDescending(t => t.CustomFields["XXX.YYY.TestCaseID"].Value.ToString())
                .ToList();

            this.testCases.Clear();
            foreach (ITestCase iTC in templist)
            {
                testCases.Add(iTC);
            }`